# Numbering identical grouped values with the same number in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an example dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1), 
                y = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "z"))
```

and I can get the `row_number()` by group easily:

```
x %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    mutate(id = row_number())


x y id
1 a  1
1 a  2
2 b  1
2 b  2
3 c  1
3 c  2
4 d  1
4 d  2
1 z  3
```

What I *want*, however, is to number identical combinations of `x$x` and `x$y` with the same number, e.g.,

```
x y id
1 a  1
1 a  1
2 b  1
2 b  1
3 c  1
3 c  1
4 d  1
4 d  1
1 z  2
```

so that where `c(x$x[1], x&y[1]) == c(x$x[2], x$y[2]) == c(x$x[n], x$y[n]` all get the same value in the  new column.

How can I do that in `dplyr`?

Comment: Do you mean identical combination compared from the previous line? or identical to one another (i.e. `x$x == x$y`)?

Comment: `x %>% group_by_all() %>% filter(n() == 2)`

Comment: @akash87 I updated the question with (hopefully!) a better data frame and better question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution using `factor`:

```
## levels=unique(y) is so that levels of y are numbered according to their order of appearance and not alphabetical order
df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(id=as.numeric(factor(y,levels=unique(y))))
```

It returns:

```
  x     y     id
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1     a     1
2     1     a     1
3     2     b     1
4     2     b     1
5     3     c     1
6     3     c     1
7     4     d     1
8     4     d     1
9     1     z     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- data_frame(x = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1), 
                y = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "z"))

x %>% 
  group_by(x,y) %>% 
  summarise(y_list = list(y)) %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest() %>% 
  select(-y_list)

#output
      x     y    id
  <dbl> <chr> <int>
1     1     a     1
2     1     a     1
3     1     z     2
4     2     b     1
5     2     b     1
6     3     c     1
7     3     c     1
8     4     d     1
9     4     d     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option we can use is `match`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
   group_by(x) %>% 
   mutate(id = match(y, unique(y)))
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups: x [4]
#      x      y    id
#  <dbl> <fctr> <int>
#1     1      a     1
#2     1      a     1
#3     2      b     1
#4     2      b     1
#5     3      c     1
#6     3      c     1
#7     4      d     1
#8     4      d     1
#9     1      z     2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x          %>% 
arrange(x) %>% 
mutate(xid = lag(x$x, default = 1), 
       yid = lag(as.character(x$y), default = "a")) %>% 
group_by(x) %>%
mutate(id = cumsum(x != xid | as.character(y) != yid) + 1) %>% 
mutate(xid = NULL, yid = NULL)
```

This yields:

```
      x      y    id
  <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>
1     1      a     1
2     1      a     1
3     1      z     2
4     2      b     1
5     2      b     1
6     3      c     1
7     3      c     1
8     4      d     1
9     4      d     1
```